# How to show a series is uniformly convergent?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, boundary-value-problem

[image]

For $(a)$ I got $$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8}{\pi^3 n^3} e^{(\alpha - \pi^2 n^2)t} \sin(\pi n x)$$

Which I'm certain is correct.

Now for $(b)$, I know that if $x$ is an integer, then the result is $0$. If $x$ is not an integer: if $\alpha <\pi^2 n^2$ then the result is $0$ and if $\alpha >=\pi^2 n^2$ then the result is infinity. But the part I'm having issues is showing that $u(x,t)$ is uniform convergent, I have no idea how to do this and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\left|\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{8}{\pi^3n^3}e^{(\alpha-\pi^2n^2)t}\sin(\pi n x)\right| \leq \frac{8}{\pi^3}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^3}
\end{align}
provided $t \in (0, \infty)$ and $\alpha-\pi^2\leq 0$, then by Wierestrass's M-test we have that the original series converges uniformly for all $t \in(0, \infty)$.

In the other case when $\alpha-\pi^2\geq 0$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\left|\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{8}{\pi^3n^3}e^{(\alpha-\pi^2n^2)t}\sin(\pi n x)\right| \leq \frac{8e^{\alpha t}}{\pi^3}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^3} \leq \frac{8e^{\alpha T}}{\pi^3}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^3} 
\end{align}
for all fixed $T>0$. Hence the series converges uniformly on any compact interval $[0, T]$.

Comment: Ohhh. $e^{(\alpha-\pi^2n^2)t} <= e^{(\alpha)t}$ for $t>0$! That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: It should be  $e^{(\alpha-\pi^2n^2)t}\leq 1$ since $\alpha-\pi^2n^2\leq 0$ and $t>0$.

Comment: Wait, if that's the case, what if $\alpha > \pi^2 n^2$

Comment: Or should I show convergence for both cases separately?

Comment: If your $\alpha-\pi^2\leq 0$, then your series will converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Otherwise, it will only converge uniformly on compact intervals say $[0, T]$.

Comment: Do you still need me to elaborate?

Comment: I was just thinking, shouldn't we be looking at the cases $\alpha-\pi^2 n^2 \leq 0$ rather than $\alpha-\pi^2\leq 0$

Comment: When $n$ is large, then it's not a problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you think my cases are correct?  (In the question where I look at the cases of alpha and x)